# Is there a tool to make a c compiler in win7 with yacc and lex?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

The only tool is found is this [Parser Generator](http://www.bumblebeesoftware.com/downloads.htm):

```
Operating System:   Windows 95 / 98 / ME / NT / 2000 / XP
```

But seems it's not supporting `win7`,when I try to build for Visual C++(32 bit), got this error:

```
yyaslvar.c
C:\Program Files\Parser Generator 2\Cpp\Source\yyaslvar.c(35) : error C2099: initializer is not a constant
C:\Program Files\Parser Generator 2\Cpp\Source\yyaslvar.c(36) : error C2099: initializer is not a constant
C:\Program Files\Parser Generator 2\Cpp\Source\yyaslvar.c(37) : error C2099: initializer is not a constant

FILE YYFAR *YYNEAR YYDCDECL yyin = stdin;
FILE YYFAR *YYNEAR YYDCDECL yyout = stdout;
FILE YYFAR *YYNEAR YYDCDECL yylexererr = stderr;
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about VS2010, but I've used this Win32 port of Lex/Yacc (Flex/Bison) on VS2005 without problems: http://userpages.monmouth.com/~wstreett/lex-yacc/lex-yacc.html

Also, your error is due to the fact that VC++ actually defines `stdin`, `stdout` etc. as macros which expand to function calls that return a `FILE *`. Clearly, these are not compile-time constants, which is what the error says.

Comment: How am I supposed to use flex.exe and bison.exe in my compiler written in c?I was expecting for some header and libraries,but not executables..

Comment: @yoyo: Flex and Bison are lexer and parser generators respectively. You don't need any headers and libraries, these tools will generate all the C code that you require. Search for Flex/Bison tutorials and you will find plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy with windows. If you are ready to shell out some money , then you can use MKS lex and Yacc toolkit

- http://www.mkssoftware.com/products/ly/

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with Win7 per se, and everything to do with (stricter!) ANSI C standards.  The C compiler simply won't let you assign a macro (like "stdin" or "stdout") to a "non-automatic variable":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t801az8a%28VS.80%29.aspx

Here's one workaround:

> http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2009-10/msg00982.html
>
> stdin and stdout need not be constants, so you can't use them to
>   initalise static or global variables.
>   Do the assignments in an initialisation function instead.

Moreover, this link might get you pointed in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730877%28VS.80%29.aspx

'Hope that helps